# Iterate over immutablejs Map values in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, immutable.js

I'd like to iterate over the values of an immutable.js Map with a `for` loop, as that's the preferred way in TypeScript, especially with the iterator protocol. I'm looking for something like

```
const map = Map<string, number>();
for (const num of map.values()) {
    ...
}
```

However, `map.values()` "is no array, no string, and has no Symbol.iterator method".

Answer (score 0):

User **valueSeq()** method instead of **values()** to iterate over the Map.

You can use **forEach** or **for** like following

```js
const map1 = Immutable.Map({
  abc: 9999,
  def: 1111,
  ghi: 4444,
  jkl: 23
});

map1.valueSeq().forEach(v => console.log(v));

for (const num of map1.valueSeq()) {
  console.log('num ', num)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/3.8.2/immutable.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and snippet, it works with JavaScript. Have you tried with TypeScript? I get `[ts] Type "Indexed<number>" is no array type...` for the `for` loop.

Comment: user map1.valueSeq().toArray() in typescript

Comment: Well, that is not beautiful and rather expensive, but is works. Guess I have to fiddle with the iterators manually.